# What's wrong with my setters and getters?

Tags: java, getter-setter

I'm very new to java and my code doesn't seem to work. Help please.
I have this class Account

```
public class Account {
    private String name;
    private double balance;


    Account(){
        name = null;
        balance = 0;
    }

    Account(String name, double balance){
        setName(name);
//        this.name = name;
        setBalance(balance);
//        this.balance = balance;
        System.out.println(this.name + " " + this.balance);
    }

    private void setName(String name){
        if (name == null){
            System.out.println("Invalid Name");
        }
        else this.name = name;
    }

    private void setBalance(double balance) {
        if (balance < 0){
            System.out.println("Balance should not be negative");
        }
        else this.balance = balance;
    }

    private String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public double withdraw(double amount){
        if (amount < this.balance){

     this.balance = balance - amount;
        }
        else if (amount > this.balance) {
            System.out.println("Balance is less than Withdrawal Amount.\nCheck balance and try again");
        }
        else;   
        System.out.println(this.name + " " + this.balance);
        return this.balance; 
        }   
}
```

and I have this in my main class

```
Account MySavingsAccount = new Account("myName", 1000);
        MySavingsAccount.withdraw(600);
```

How come it does not print the correct balance?

Comment: What's the input and what does the wrong output looks like?

Comment: `else;` is unnecessary. The else clause is optional.

Comment: Works fine for me too.

Comment: Just wondering, why are your getters private, there are only few instances where there is a point in them being private, and your certainly is not one of them.

Comment: What does it actually print? If you do not tell us, we can simply assume you do not have a problem at all. It is a required good practice, when you describe a problem, to tell us how should it work (here it is obvious) and how exactly the code is failing to do its job

Comment: The input based on the main class is "myName" with the balance 1000. with the withdraw amount of 600 the balance should then be 400, but it still prints 1000. why?

Comment: @Jasmine, but what does it print in the console? From your code, it should print once this `myName 1000` (from the constructor) and a second time `myName 400` (upon withdraw). What does it actually print?

Comment: it prints myName 1000 first, then it prints this - Balance is less than Withdrawal Amount.
Check balance and try again

Comment: I'm also using netbeans IDE and it suggests to make the setters and getters private

Comment: Unrelated: your code currently does nothing when `amount == balance` (there is no error and the balance stays the same).

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @FernandoMatsumoto

Comment: My result is the same as @IvayloSlavov.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. I think it's all good now :)